# Find the value of $m?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let  C be the  circle  $|z|=\frac{3}{2}$  in the  complex plane  that is oriented  in the  counter clock  wise  direction. Find the  value  of  $m$ for which  $$\int_{C}  \frac{z+1}{z^2-3z+2}  +\frac{m}{z-1} dz =0$$

**My attempt** :At $z= 1$ is a  point of singularity  in the  given domain $|z|=\frac{3}{2}$

$$\int_{C}  \frac{(z+1)/(z-2)}{(z-1)}  +\frac{m}{z-1} dz =0 \implies  2i\pi (-2)+2i\pi m=0$$

$$2i\pi (-2)+2i\pi m=0 \implies m=2$$

Am i right ?

Comment: 2 isn't in the domain, it's outside the domain.  1 is in the domain

Comment: @Alan okay that  mean  $1$ is  the singularity.Am i right ?

Comment: @wasiu Yes, you have just to consider the singularity $1$ instead of $2$.